# Bootstrap carousel not working after URL routing ASP.NET

Tags: asp.net, twitter-bootstrap, url, routes, slider

I've used the Twitter Bootstrap Carousel slider which works fine, but after URL routing using Global.asax file, it stopped working when it's on the routed URL's, however... If i go to e.g. default.aspx, a non-routed URL, it works fine.

I checked file paths and stuff already obviously, and fixed them after routing, but still it's not working.

Can anyone tell me what's wrong with it?

```
<div id="carousel-slider" class="carousel slide">
        <!-- class of slide for animation -->
        <div class="carousel-inner">
            <div class="item active">
                <!-- class of active since it's the first item -->
                <asp:Image ImageUrl="~/assets/img/slider1.jpg" AlternateText="Slider #1" runat="server" />
            </div>
            <div class="item">
                <asp:Image ImageUrl="~/assets/img/slider2.jpg" AlternateText="Slider #1" runat="server" />
            </div>
            <div class="item">
                <asp:Image ImageUrl="~/assets/img/slider3.jpg" AlternateText="Slider #1" runat="server" />
            </div>
            <div class="item">
                <asp:Image ImageUrl="~/assets/img/slider4.jpg" AlternateText="Slider #1" runat="server" />
            </div>
        </div>
        <!-- /.carousel-inner -->
        <!--  Next and Previous controls below
    href values must reference the id for this carousel -->
    </div>

    <script>
        $(document).ready(function () {
            $('.carousel').carousel({
                interval: 5000
            });
        });
    </script>
```

I also have tried using normal  tags, but using asp.net tags allows me to ~/ and always go back to root, none of the two ways worked, the slider simply isn't "sliding".

SOLUTION:

Apparently Bootstrap.min.js wasn't being loaded properly when on the routed URL pages, but on default.aspx it was. I fixed this by changing the path with ../ infront of the original path.

Comment: provide your code here please.

Comment: There we go. Sorry abou that.

Comment: Is it necessary for you to have the server Image control `<asp:Image` rather than html control `<img` ?

Comment: It's not "necessary", but I use it because then I'm always sure it goes back to root, whereas if I use HTML img I have to do ../../, but it doesn't work either way, I tried both things, neither works

Answer (score 0):

Try to put the image urls in ResolveUrl method and check the result:
Also if you are not using the server controls from the code behind it's better to use the HTML controls instead like this:

> ```
>  <img src='<%: ResolveUrl("~/assets/img/slider1.jpg") %>' alt="" />
> ```

**UPDATE 1**

You should also use  `data-ride="carousel"` in your div tag like below:

> ```
> <div id="carousel-slider" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel">
> ```

and use the html control above to display images as well.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but unfortunately, this doesn't fix the issue, it's still just stuck on the first slide image

Comment: Still only working on default.aspx unfortunately, still not on the routed URL's.

Comment: make sure that you have all the bootstrap refrence on your page correctly, to check that you need to right click on your browser and select view source to make sure your bootstrap references all are working correctly

Comment: I've got jQuery from Google CDN, Modernizr locally stored, Bootstrap min.js locally stored, and of course, Bootstrap CSS and my own CSS. The thing is, the slider works just the way it's supposed to when I go to www.URLHERE.com/default.aspx, but when I go to www.URLHERE.com/forside/ - which is the routed URL, it doesn't work.

Comment: I managed to fix it, apparently it wasn't loading the Bootstrap min.js properly when on the routed URL's, but it loaded it just fine on default.aspx, thank you for your help, couldn't have fixed it without your help!

Comment: I'm glad you fixed it.

Answer (score 0):

Apparently Bootstrap.min.js wasn't being loaded properly when on the routed URL pages, but on default.aspx it was. I fixed this by changing the path with ../ infront of the original path.